# Setting geographical Area boundaries Bing Maps in Power Apps

Tags: bing-maps, powerapps

I am developing a power apps application for Employee Check-in to get their time and location, I need to set boundaries on the map to generate an error message if the employee checks in outside of the area. How can I do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you map out your coordinates to get a box, for example:

X1 — x2
|            |
X3— -x4

Now you can check at the moment the user signs in if:

lattitude user >= lattitude[x1,x3] and <= latitude[x2,x4]
AND longitude user >= longitude[x3,x4] and <= longitude[x1,x2]